# In Windows Store apps, Figuring out if text in TextBox is right-to-left

Tags: c#, input, windows-runtime

I have an application where the user can input arbitrary text in a textbox. we are currently having trouble with right-to-left languages, as we are not just displaying the text in a TextBlock or so, but using it differently (we add the text to a PDF. PDF's don't have right-to-left language support included, which means we need to place individual characters). The character ordering in right-to-left languages when getting the text from a textbox (TextBox.TexT) is in logical order (the order the keys were hit in) as opposed to in display order.

I was wondering if there are any build in ways of retrieving text in display order rather than logical order (perhaps if you're using a RichEditBox) as I would prefer not to have to look at each single character and figure out if I should add the next character to the left or right of it.

Thanks,
Tomas